# Errors for POM.XML file in CentOS

Tags: maven, centos7

I am using CentOS 7, Maven3.6.0, Java 8.
Trying to build a .war package for my project but when I execute the command, it downloads the required files and at the end throw errors.
I am attaching the errors here along with POM.XML file.

please let me know what is wrong with it.
[Link to POM.XML file I am using](https://github.com/OHDSI/WebAPI/blob/master/pom.xml)
TIA

and below the error [image]

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM /root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.7/jackson-bom-2.8.7.pom: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...psis = true;\n    }\n\n\tvar recipientsList = "";\n\n\tfor (var i=0; i < ... @184:20)  @ /root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.7/jackson-bom-2.8.7.pom, line 184, column 20
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-bom/2.7/log4j-bom-2.7.pom: start tag unexpected character ; (position: TEXT seen ...\n\tvar recipientsList = "";\n\n\tfor (var i=0; i<recipientsArr.length;... @184:39)  @ /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-bom/2.7/log4j-bom-2.7.pom, line 184, column 39
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.ohdsi:WebAPI:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/root/WebAPI/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM /root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.7/jackson-bom-2.8.7.pom: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...psis = true;\n    }\n\n\tvar recipientsList = "";\n\n\tfor (var i=0; i < ... @184:20)  @ /root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.8.7/jackson-bom-2.8.7.pom, line 184, column 20 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-bom/2.7/log4j-bom-2.7.pom: start tag unexpected character ; (position: TEXT seen ...\n\tvar recipientsList = "";\n\n\tfor (var i=0; i<recipientsArr.length;... @184:39)  @ /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-bom/2.7/log4j-bom-2.7.pom, line 184, column 39 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
```

below is the component of POM.xml for which the error is showing up:

// Render recipient list from and array. // String[] recipientsArr - Array of recipients. // [int ellipsisLimit] - A string beyond this length will be cut and added ellipsis. Optional, default is 0 - no ellipsis. // [bool useLinebreakes] - Should a line break be added after each recipient. Optional, default is true.

```
function recipientsArr2StrInTable(recipientsArr, ellipsisLimit, 
useLinebreakes)
if (ellipsisLimit == undefined)
{
ellipsisLimit = 0;
}

if (useLinebreakes == undefined)
{
useEllipsis = true;
}

var recipientsList = "";

for (var i=0; i<recipientsArr.length; i++)
{
recipientsList += HTMLEncode(recipientsArr[i].address);
if (i < recipientsArr.length-1)
{
    recipientsList += ", ";
    if (useLinebreakes)
    {
        recipientsList += "<br>";
    }
}
}

if (ellipsisLimit > 0)
{
//recipientsList = Ext.util.Format.ellipsis(recipientsList, 
ellipsisLimit);
recipientsList = recipientsList;
}

return recipientsList;
}
```

Please suggest.

TIA

Comment: Add `com.google.code.gson` version in your pom.xml and here's the latest [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5)

Comment: got some weird error. I have updated the original question and added errors and the code throwing error.

Comment: Did you happen to copy to paste the entire pom.xml by any chance? Looks like you have unwanted text which can be space or semicolon(start tag unexpected character ; ) as the error says. Do look at [this](https://cwiki.apache.org//confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException), [this](https://cwiki.apache.org//confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException) and [this](https://www.buggybread.com/2016/12/error-fatal-non-parseable-pom-pomxml.html)